# Apache Atlas Production setup using Managed Cassandra and Apache Solr

Tags: cassandra, apache-atlas

I am looking for documentation or any other resource to setup Apache Atlas for Production using independent Solr and Cassandra instances. The goal is to have a persistent storage for the Apache Atlas.

Comment: Jassy  paji any info you have gathered on this topic ?  If yes can you please share